# Changing the width of an element only in IE browsers using javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to change the width of an element specifically only in IE browsers using javascript, but not getting any idea of how to do this.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Why only in IE? If possible, you should use a solution that is the same across all browers, otherwise it might break the next time MS releases an update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional comments, or detect the browser using javascript. Then just retrieve the element using `document.getElementById('id')`, and change its width.

For example:

```
document.onload = function()
{
 if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
 {
   document.getElementById('someElement').style.width = '200px';
 }
}

<div id='someElement' style='width:10px'>Some element</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('elementsId').style.width = '250px';
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```